# how to add one column in order in admin panel

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to add one column in order page which is show in admin panle
i update my database in **sales_order** and s**ales_order_grid** by using upgrade scheme but i does not show in order in admin panel please help me thank you 
xml file here


    
        
            
                
                    text
                    true
                    newcoll

Comment: show your complete code

Answer (score 0):

If you've already added the column(s) in the `sales_order_grid` the next step is to define the column in an **ui_component** extension in your module. To do this for the order grid create a file **app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="your_column_field">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Your Label Here</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: when i write above code and go to admin panel there is no change but warning message "One or more integrations have been reset because of a change to their xml configs.  "  what is it ?

Comment: Did you change "you_column_field" to the right column name? Not sure about the message though.

Answer (score 0):

I created a UI component sales_order_grid.xml under

> [Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

and add the following code to your **sales_order_grid.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="export_status" class="[Vendor]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Giftstatus">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Gift Option</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Then created the UI class under

> [Vendor]/[Module]/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Giftstatus.php

add the following code to your **Giftstatus.php**:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Giftstatus extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(ContextInterface $context, UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria, array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $status = $order->getData("gift_message_id");

                if($status){
                    $message = 'Yes';
                }
                else{
                    $message = 'No';
                }

                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $message;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

This is working for Gift Option is there or not. You can modify it according to your requirement.